# converting from intel assembly to gas/at&t

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

so can someone just do this tranlation for me? from intel assembly to at&t assembly? I'm learning gas syntax but having a little difficulty understanding some petty things...

```
mov ecx, dword ptr[esp + 0xC + 0xC]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [GAS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory) has a pretty good explanation of how to write memory references in AT&T syntax.

In this case, I think you'd want

```
movl (0xc + 0xc)(%esp), %ecx
```

Comment: Also you can just assemble and disassembe in intel syntax.